# Try to define should or should_not by method option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I need test sidebars on every site page.
I define user method `test_all_sidebars` and fill in

```
def test_all_sidebars
    test_header
    test_contacts
    test_news
    test_footer
end
```

then I need test for one page 2 sidebars will not show. Example:

```
describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    test_all_sidebars
end
describe "Contact page" do
    before { visit contact_path }

    test_header
    test_footer
    test_news(false)
    test_contact(false)
end
```

I try to define `test_news` and `test_contact` with option like this

```
def test_contacts(flag: true)
    describe "sidebar with contacts" do
        it { (:flag ? should : should_not) have_content('phone: ') }
    end
```

but it doesnt work. I have  `unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'`

I tried use `let`

```
def test_contacts(flag: true)
    if :flag then
        let(:sh) { should }
    else
        let(:sh) { should_not }
    end
    it { sh have_content('phone: ') }
end
```

but this still doesnt work.

My question: HOW? How I can use `should`/`should_not` in same method using input data condition?

Comment: Try using `shared_examples_for` (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test_contacts(flag: true)
  describe "sidebar with contacts" do
    it { (:flag ? should : should_not) have_content('phone: ') }
  end
end
```

So much is wrong with this code:

1. `:flag` is *always* truthy, since it is a symbol. If you want to check if the value passed it `true` you should use `flag` (the variable), not `:flag` (the symbol)
2. `should` and `should_not` are methods, so actually you need to call either `should(have_content('phone: ')` or `should_not(have_content('phone: ')` - you can't separate the method call from the variables you send it.

So, inside your describe your code should look like:

```
it { flag ? should(have_content('phone: ')) : should_not(have_content('phone: ') }
```

Beside this, I've never seen this kind of pattern for writing rspec test cases, and I'm pretty sure you are better off using better idioms like [`shared_examples_for`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group)

Comment: Thank you so much! Its 2 my terrible mistake. I only want refactor my test code: not define 2 different mathods only for `should`/`should_not`. I hate spagetti code. So I am understanding now that I dont want use my first implementation. I read all article by link. However I dont understand how I can use its in my case. Can You help me with it, please, @UriAgassi?

Comment: @goodniceweb - I suggest you make you current code work, and then post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/